# How to print a Triangle Pyramid pattern using a for loop in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using the following `for` loop code to print a star pattern and the code is working perfectly fine.

Here is my code:

```
for i in range(1,6):
    for j in range(i):
        print("*", end=" ")
    print()
```

This code displays:

```
* 
* * 
* * * 
* * * * 
* * * * *
```

Now, my question is how to print the output like this:

```
         * 
        * * 
       * * * 
      * * * * 
     * * * * *
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to add spaces before the `*`:

```
for i in range(1,6):
    for j in range(6-i):
        print(" ", end="")
    for j in range(i):
        print("*", end=" ")
    print()
```

Answer (score 5):

Actually, that can be done in a single loop:

```
for i in range(1, 6):
  print (' ' * (5 - i), '* ' * i)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```py
def triangle(n): 
  k = 2*n - 2
  for i in range(0, n):  
   
    for j in range(0, k): 
        print(end=" ") 
  
    k = k - 1
    
    for j in range(0, i+1): 
        print("* ", end="") 
    
    print("\r") 
 
n = 5
triangle(n)
```

Description:

1. The 1st line defines the function demonstrating how to print the pattern
2. The 2nd line is for the number of spaces
3. The 3rd line is for the outer loop to handle number of rows
4. Inside the outer loop, the 1st inner loop handles the number of spaces and the values change according to requirements
5. After each iteration of the outer loop, `k` is decremented
6. After decrementing the `k` value, the 2nd inner loop handles the number of columns and the values change according to the outer loop
7. Print '*' based on `j`
8. End the line after each row

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved in one loop and center padding.

```
n = int(input('Enter the row you want to print:- '))
sym = input('Enter the symbol you want to print:- ')
for i in range(n):
    print((sym * ((2 * i) + 1)).center((2 * n) - 1, ' '))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# right angle triangle
for i in range(1, 10):
    print("* " * i)

# equilateral triangle
# using reverse of range
for i , j in zip(range(1, 10), reversed(range(1, 10)):
    print(" " * j + "* " * i)

# using only range()
for i, j in zip(range(1, 10), range(10, -1, -1):
    print(" " * j + "* " * i)
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in a single loop like the code below:

```
j=1
for i in range(10,0,-1):
    print(" "*i,"*"*j)
    j+=2
```

Answer (score 1):

**Method #1: Comprehension version**

This could be easiest way to print any pattern in `Python`

```
n = 5
print('\n'.join([('* '*i).center(2*n) for i in range(1,n+1)]))
```

Use `center` method of `str`, give it a width as parameter and it will centered the whole string accordingly.

**Method #2: Regular version**

```
n = 5
for i in range(1,n+1):
  print(('* '*i).center(2*n))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the easiest way to print this pattern:

```
n = int(input("Enter the number of rows: "))
for i in range(1,n+1):
    print(" "*(n-i) + "* "*i)
```

You have to print spaces `(n-i)` times, where `n` is the number of rows and `i` is for the loop variable, and add it to the stars `i` times.

Answer (score 1):

```
#n=Number of rows
def get_triangle(n):
    space,star=" ","* "
    for i in range(1,n+1):
         print((n-i)*space + star*i)

get_triangle(5)
```

Where `n` is the number of rows and I is a variable for the loop, you must print spaces `(n-i)` times and then add it with stars `I` times. You'll get the desired pattern as a result. For better comprehension, go to the code stated above.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way

```
size = 7
m = (2 * size) - 2
for i in range(0, size):
    for j in range(0, m):
        print(end=" ")
    m = m - 1 # decrementing m after each loop
    for j in range(0, i + 1):
        # printing full Triangle pyramid using stars
        print("* ", end=' ')
    print(" ")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def triangle(val: str, n: int, type: str):
    for i in range(n):
        if type == "regular":
            print((i + 1) * val)
        elif type == "reversed":
            print((n - i) * val)
        elif type == "inverted":
            print((n - (i + 1)) * " " + (i + 1) * val)
        elif type == "inverted reversed":
            print(i * " " + (val * (n - i)))
        elif type == "triangle":
            print((n - (i + 1)) * " " + ((2*i)+1) * val)
```

**Call the function like this**

```
triangle("*", 5, 'triangle')
```

**Output**

```
    *
   ***
  *****
 *******
*********
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#prints pyramid for given lines 
l = int(input('Enter no of lines'))
for i in range(1,l +1):
    print(' ' * (l-i), ('*') * (i*2-1))
```

Answer (score -1):

.very simple answer.. don't go for complex codes..

first try to draw a pyramid. by * ..then u easly understand the code..my solution is.. simplest..here example of 5 lines pyramid..

```
number_space  =  5
for   i   in   range (5)

     print('/r')

     print (number_space *"  ", end='')

     number_space=number_space-1

     for star in range (i+1):

                print("*",end="  ")
```

Answer (score -1):

Use String Multiplication,
To simply multiply a string, this is the most straightforward way to go about doing it:

num = 5
for e in range(num, 0, -1):
print(" "*(e-1)+("*"*(num-e+1))+("*"*(num-e)))

Answer (score -1):

```
j=1

for i in range(5,0,-1):
    
    print(" "*i, end="")
    
    while j<6:
        print("* "*j)
        j=j+1
        break
```

Comment: your pyramid, isnt right top star is not where it should be

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score -2):

```
function printPyramid($n)
{
    //example 1
    for ($x = 1; $x <= $n; $x++) {
        for ($y = 1; $y <= $x; $y++) {
            echo 'x';
        }
        echo "\n";
    }

    // example 2
    for ($x = 1; $x <= $n; $x++) {
        for ($y = $n; $y >= $x; $y--) {
            echo 'x';
        }
        echo "\n";
    }

    // example 3

    for($x = 0; $x < $n; $x++) {
        for($y = 0; $y < $n - $x; $y++) {
            echo ' ';
        }
        for($z = 0; $z < $x * 2 +1; $z++) {
            echo 'x';
        }
        echo "\n";
    }


}
```

Answer (score -2):

#CPP Program for Print the dynamic pyramid pattern by using one loop in one line.

https://www.linkedin.com/posts/akashdarji8320_cpp-cplusplus-c-activity-6683972516999950336-ttlP

```
#include

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int rows;

    cout<<"Enter number of rows :: ";
    cin>>rows;

    for( int i = 1, j = rows, k = rows; i <= rows*rows; i++ )
        if( i >= j && cout<<"*" && i % k == 0 && (j += rows-1) && cout<<endl || cout<<" " );
}
```

Comment: Read the question again: OP is using Python, not C++.