# Building a pyramid of asterisks in python, the only input being the number of layers the pyramid should have,

Tags: python

Its a beginner project, here's what I have got so far:

```
def tower_builder(n_floors):
   tower = []
   x=1
   for i in range(1,n_floors+1):
        tower.append((x)*"*")
        x=x+2
   return tower
```

the only problem I have is returning the contents of the array "tower" on separate lines. How do I do this.
Also I know my code is not the most efficient but I am learning. Thanks!

Comment: instead of `return tower`, try `print('\n'.join(tower))`, but is this what you want or should it be centered?

Comment: do you have an main function or where do you call tower_builder?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Print Triangle Pyramid pattern using for loop python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53766610/print-triangle-pyramid-pattern-using-for-loop-python)

Comment: @mozway, Thats it! although if there is a way to centre it, that would be preferred

Comment: @Poder Psittacus
this is just the function, I call it later on

Comment: @DrMowri to center it, use `tower.append(' '*(n_floors-x//2)+x*"*")` (if you do not want to use any automatic formatting function)

Comment: For a one liner: `print('\n'.join([('*'*(2*i+1)).center(2*n_floors-1) for i in range(n_floors)]))`

Answer (score 0):

You could use format specifier to center the tower:

```
def tower_builder(n_floors):
    for i in range(n_floors):
        print(f"{'*' * (2*i+1): ^80}")
```