# Printing a number, the same number of times

Tags: python, graphics, numbers

I would like to create the following pattern:

```
1

2 2

3 3 3 

4 4 4 4 

5 5 5 5 5
```

Here is my attempt:

```
def print_numbers(number):
    for i in range(number):
        print(i * i)
```

Now clearly this will return the product of the number with itself. I would like to specify this function to print out the number that many times. So something like print(i) * i which is not correct syntax of course. How would I about doing this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Print Triangle Pyramid pattern using for loop python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53766610/print-triangle-pyramid-pattern-using-for-loop-python)

Comment: Where you said `print(i)*i` you were quite close; try `print(str(i)*i)`, like @MichaelButscher suggested

Comment: @JoshuaVoskamp That question is about printing a triangle of `*` characters, not numbers. And it's about how to get the point in the middle rather than the left. Nothing like this question.

Comment: @Barmar I understand the difference between the two questions. They're very similar; in a loop, print something some number of times equal to the current iteration count.

Comment: @JoshuaVoskamp But the difference between string and number is important. The code they tried is like the solution to that question, but it doesn't work because `i` is not a string.

Comment: @JoshuaVoskamp And if you think "well, they just have to convert it to a string" -- that's what they couldn't figure out in the first place, and the other question won't help.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Barmar you can convert the number into strings and multiply with same number.

```
#Ex  str(4)*3 = 444  #It will print 3times 4.

def print_numbers(number):
    for i in range(number+1):  
        print((str(i)+" ")*i) #Converted number into string and multiply with the same number.
    
print_numbers(5)
```

**Output:**

```
1 
2 2 
3 3 3 
4 4 4 4 
5 5 5 5 5
```

If you wanted a line space b/w each number you can print like: `print((str(i)+" ")*i+"\n")` This will give.

```
1 

2 2 

3 3 3 

4 4 4 4 

5 5 5 5 5
```